# linux file size

Tags: php, linux, shell

i am using this **exec("du -sh -S ".$fileFlv."");** command in php to get size of a file all the things works fine but the problem at my end is i want only the size but it dispalys the size as well as name of the file

Comment: Why don't you use filesize()? http://www.php.net/filesize

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried the [filesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function?

Comment: Note: don't forget that php caches the filesize() result.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the size or other properties of a single file, you can use stat instead of du. (There's probably built-in PHP functionality for this too.) The -c option lets you customize the output format. Here's the size in bytes.

```
stat -c %s myfile.txt
```

If you really want du (to get total size of directories), you can use cut to munge the output.

```
du -sh -S mydir | cut -f1
```

Or just capture the output to a string in PHP and strip the filename there.